# Convert Int to date formatter followed with timezone

Tags: swift, timezone, nsdateformatter, dateformatter, nsformatter

Trying to convert Int to formatted string date with supplied timezone value and formatter to expected result **"12/01/2022 09:03:41 PM THA"**.

//Response Data.

```
{
      "code": "THA",
      "name": "Thailand Standard Time (THA) (UTC+07)",
      "offset": 25200,
      "utc_offset": "UTC+07",
      "region": "Asia/Phnom_Penh"
}
```

I have picked Timezone from api response code, Here is what I have implemented.

```
   var timezoneCode = response.timeZone.code ?? ""

    if let updatedOn = self.dict?["updated_on"]?.intValue{ // i.e., 1669903421000
        let dateValue =  Date(milliseconds: Int64(updatedOn))
        stringDate = dateToStringTimeZone(date: dateValue, dateFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz", timeZone: timezoneCode)
    }
```

// convert Data To String with Timezone / DateFormate

```
func dateToStringTimeZone(date: Date, dateFormat: String, timeZone: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: timeZone)
    let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return dateStr
}
```

// Date Extension

```
extension Date {
    var millisecondsSince1970: Int64 {
        return Int64((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
    }

    init(milliseconds: Int64) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds) / 1000)
    }
}
```

After Trying it the above code resultant String date

**"12/01/2022 07:33:41 PM GMT+5:30"**

Can any one guild how to achive the formatted date value as shown below?

**"12/01/2022 09:03:41 PM THA"**

Comment: Apparently the "zzz" format string falls back to offset from GMT if it can't figure out the time zone. That is probably what's happening to you. See Joakim's answer, where they suggest simply putting the time zone into your date formatter as a literal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace "zzz" with your wanted timezone code directly in the date format string

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a '\(timezoneCode)'"
```

You also need to use another init for TimeZone, using the `offset` property seems to work

```
let offset = response.timeZone.offset
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: offset)
```